# Django form style using css

Tags: html, css, django

I created login and registrations. In the first one there was no problem to implement the changes in appearance using css. In the second case, when I use django forms, there was a problem with html editing. I can't get the focus effect and change the position of the inscription as in the first case.Here is a sample of both situations.

Login view:

a)html

```
{% extends 'computer_science_in_medicine/main.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block body_block %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/login_user.css' %} "/>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>PLEASE LOGIN</h1>
        <form action="{% url 'accounts:user_login' %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="inputBox">
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="" required="">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
            </div>
            <div class="inputBox">
                <input type="password" name="password" required="">
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
            </div>

            <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" name="" value="Login">

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

b) css

```
.jumbotron {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
width: 600px;
padding: 70px;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
box-sizing: border-box;
box-shadow: 0 15px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
border-radius: 30px;
}

.jumbotron h1 {
 margin: 0 0 30px;
    padding: 0;
    color: #fbfbfb;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
 }

  .jumbotron .inputBox {
   position: relative;
}

  .jumbotron .inputBox input {
   width: 100%;
   padding: 10px 0;
    font-size: 22px;
   color: #fbfbfb;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
letter-spacing: 2px;
border: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid #fbfbfb;
outline: none;
background: transparent;
}

  .jumbotron .inputBox label {
    position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fbfbfb;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: .5s;
}

 .jumbotron .inputBox input:focus ~ label,
 .jumbotron .inputBox input:valid ~ label {
  top: -18px;
  left: 0;
   color: #d4939f;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

Here is the code with problem:

a) HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends 'computer_science_in_medicine/main.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block body_block %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 
'css/register_user.css' %} "/>
<div class="jumbotron">
    {% if registered %}
        <h1>Thank you for registering!</h1>
    {% else %}
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Register Here!</h1>
            <h3> Fill out the form:</h3>
            <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="inputBox">
                        {{ user_form.as_p }}
                </div>
                <div class="inputBoxFile">
                        {{ profile_form.as_p }}
                </div>
                <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" 
      name="" value="Register">
            </form>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
</div>

   {% endblock %}
```

b) css:

```
.jumbotron {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
width: 600px;
padding: 70px;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
box-sizing: border-box;
box-shadow: 0 15px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
border-radius: 30px;
 }

      .jumbotron h1, h3, span {
   margin: 0 0 10px;
   padding: 0;
  color: #fbfbfb;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  }

 .jumbotron .inputBox > p {
  position: relative;
   }

 .jumbotron .inputBoxFile > p {
   position: relative;
   }

 .jumbotron .inputBox > p > input {
   width: 100%;
   padding: 10px 0;
   font-size: 22px;
   color: #fbfbfb;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
   letter-spacing: 2px;
   border: none;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #fbfbfb;
   outline: none;
   background: transparent;
  }

.jumbotron .inputBoxFile > p > input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 25px 0;
  font-size: 22px;
   color: #fbfbfb;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fbfbfb;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
   }

.jumbotron .inputBox > p > label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 15px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fbfbfb;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: .5s;
  }

.jumbotron .inputBoxFile > p > label {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
  left: 0;
   padding: 0px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fbfbfb;
  pointer-events: none;
   transition: .5s;
  }

.jumbotron .inputBox > p > input:focus ~ label,
.jumbotron .inputBox > p > input:valid ~ p {
   top: -18px;
   left: 0;
    color: #d4939f;
   font-size: 14px;
 }
```

Comment: it's not clear whether the stylesheets in the first case and the second one must be different. Actually they are different, the second css doesnt contain classes for inputs, which make labels to reduce in size on focus.  All  .jumbotron .inputBox must be in the 2nd stylesheet if you want the same behaviour.

Comment: I am aware that if I had the same fragment of label and input, in the second case a given code would work. My question concerns the edition of "forms" generated in the template using django.